# Spacing around itemize in tabular

Tags: tables, itemize, multicol, cv

I'm working off of a resume template from writelatex.com. I'd like to use bullet points in my descriptions, rather than flowing text. However, it adds a bit to the separating line, as seen in item 1. How do I get the line to only be the length of the itemized text, similar to item 2?

Line is too long

[image: Bad Spacing]

Line is just right
[image: Good Spacing]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist[itemize]{leftmargin=*,topsep=0ex,parsep=0pt}

\usepackage{marvosym}
\usepackage{fontspec}                   %for loading fonts
\usepackage{xunicode,xltxtra,url,parskip}   %other packages for formatting
\RequirePackage{color,graphicx}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage[big]{layaureo}              %better formatting of the A4 page
% an alternative to Layaureo can be ** \usepackage{fullpage} **
\usepackage{supertabular}               %for Grades
\usepackage{titlesec}                   %custom \section

%Setup hyperref package, and colours for links
\usepackage{hyperref}
\definecolor{linkcolour}{rgb}{0,0.2,0.6}
\hypersetup{colorlinks,breaklinks,urlcolor=linkcolour, linkcolor=linkcolour}

\titleformat{\section}{\Large\scshape\raggedright}{}{0em}{}[\titlerule]
\titlespacing{\section}{0pt}{3pt}{3pt}

%--------------------BEGIN DOCUMENT----------------------
\begin{document}

\pagestyle{empty} % non-numbered pages

\font\fb=''[cmr10]'' %for use with \LaTeX command

%--------------------TITLE-------------
\par{\centering
        {\Huge Adam \textsc{G}
    }\bigskip\par}

%--------------------SECTIONS-----------------------------------

\section{Work Experience}
\begin{tabular}{r|p{11cm}}
 \emph{Current - } & Research Assistant \\\textsc{June 2012}&\emph{Speech Lab @ Queens College}\\&
 \footnotesize{
 \begin{itemize}
 \item DARPA-funded initiative to identify “cognitive fingerprints” (unique typing patterns) based on linguistic biometrics
 \item Develop, test and implement a series of linguistic feature-sets, to create unique user profiles
 \end{itemize}}\\\multicolumn{2}{c}{} \\

 \textsc{Jul-Oct 2008} & 1\textsuperscript{st} year Analyst at \textsc{Lehman Brothers}, London \\&\emph{Commodities Structured Trading}\\&\footnotesize{Developed spreadsheets for risk analysis on exotic derivatives on a wide array of commodities (\textit{ags, oils, precious} and \textit{base metals}), managed blotter and secondary trades on structured notes, liaised with Middle Office, Sales and Structuring for bookkeeping.}\\\multicolumn{2}{c}{} \\
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `after=\vspace{-\baselineskip}` to

```
\setlist[itemize]{leftmargin=*,topsep=0ex,parsep=0pt}
```

Code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist[itemize]{leftmargin=*,topsep=0ex,parsep=0pt,after=\vspace{-\baselineskip}}

\usepackage{marvosym}
\usepackage{fontspec}                   %for loading fonts
\usepackage{xunicode,xltxtra,url,parskip}   %other packages for formatting
\RequirePackage{color,graphicx}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage[big]{layaureo}              %better formatting of the A4 page
% an alternative to Layaureo can be ** \usepackage{fullpage} **
\usepackage{supertabular}               %for Grades
\usepackage{titlesec}                   %custom \section

%Setup hyperref package, and colours for links
\usepackage{hyperref}
\definecolor{linkcolour}{rgb}{0,0.2,0.6}
\hypersetup{colorlinks,breaklinks,urlcolor=linkcolour, linkcolor=linkcolour}

\titleformat{\section}{\Large\scshape\raggedright}{}{0em}{}[\titlerule]
\titlespacing{\section}{0pt}{3pt}{3pt}

%--------------------BEGIN DOCUMENT----------------------
\begin{document}

\pagestyle{empty} % non-numbered pages

\font\fb=''[cmr10]'' %for use with \LaTeX command

%--------------------TITLE-------------
\par{\centering
        {\Huge Adam \textsc{G}
    }\bigskip\par}

%--------------------SECTIONS-----------------------------------

\section{Work Experience}
\begin{tabular}{r|p{11cm}}
 \emph{Current - } & Research Assistant \\\textsc{June 2012}&\emph{Speech Lab @ Queens College}\\&
 \footnotesize{
 \begin{itemize}
 \item DARPA-funded initiative to identify “cognitive fingerprints” (unique typing patterns) based on linguistic biometrics
 \item Develop, test and implement a series of linguistic feature-sets, to create unique user profiles
 \end{itemize}}\\\multicolumn{2}{c}{} \\

 \textsc{Jul-Oct 2008} & 1\textsuperscript{st} year Analyst at \textsc{Lehman Brothers}, London \\&\emph{Commodities Structured Trading}\\&\footnotesize{Developed spreadsheets for risk analysis on exotic derivatives on a wide array of commodities (\textit{ags, oils, precious} and \textit{base metals}), managed blotter and secondary trades on structured notes, liaised with Middle Office, Sales and Structuring for bookkeeping.}\\\multicolumn{2}{c}{} \\
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

A better setting would be

```
\setlist[itemize]{leftmargin=*,nosep,after=\vspace{-\baselineskip},before=\vspace*{-0.75\baselineskip}}
```

[image]

If you want to retain the regular `itemize` environment, define a new list:

```
\usepackage{enumitem}
\newlist{myitemize}{itemize}{1}
\setlist[myitemize]{label=\textbullet,leftmargin=*,topsep=0ex,
    parsep=0pt,after=\vspace{-\baselineskip},before=\vspace{-0.75\baselineskip}}
```

and use it:

```
\begin{myitemize}
 \item DARPA-funded initiative to identify “cognitive fingerprints” (unique typing patterns) based on linguistic biometrics
 \item Develop, test and implement a series of linguistic feature-sets, to create unique user profiles
 \end{myitemize}}
```

Comment: If I also want to make a normal itemized list somewhere, is there a way to also use the default?

Comment: @Adam_G Please see the update.