# Remove list margin only inside table

Tags: itemize, enumitem, pandoc

I'm trying to style `itemize` lists that appear in tabular environments (specifically in a `longtable`). Ideally, I'd like to remove the left margin from lists that appear in tables while maintaining the margin on lists outside of tables.

There are several answers here already about how to use the `enumitem` package to change the margins of lists: [you can set `leftmargin=*` on specific lists](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/91124/itemize-removing-natural-indent), or you can [create a new custom `itemize` environment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/216089/spacing-around-itemize-in-tabular) and use it specifically inside tables.

However, I am using pandoc to convert Markdown into TeX, so I have no control over the resulting TeX output—I can't add `\begin{itemize}[leftmargin=*]` or use a custom `\begin{marginlessitemize}`. `enumitem` has a `\setlist` macro that lets you set list settings globally, and `\setlist[itemize]{leftmargin=*}` removes the left margin from all lists, which isn't ideal, since I'm only trying to target lists inside tables.

Is there a way to apply `\setlist{...}` *only* to itemize environments that are nested inside tabular environments? In a perfect world, it'd be cool to use some sort of logic in the preamble: if `itemize` is in a table, use no margin; otherwise use a margin.

---

Here's a MWE…

(The messy `longtable` output comes from this Markdown table, which pandoc converts into TeX):

```
+-----------+-----------+
| Thing     | List      |
+===========+===========+
| Thing 1   | - Item 1  |
|           | - Item 2  |
+-----------+-----------+
| Thing 2   | - Item 3  |
|           | - Item 4  |
+-----------+-----------+
```

This TeX file…

```
\documentclass[11pt,article,oneside]{memoir}

\usepackage{longtable}

\begin{document}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.

\begin{itemize}
\tightlist
\item
  Item 1
\item
  Item 2
\end{itemize}

\begin{longtable}[]{@{}ll@{}}
\caption{This is a table.}\tabularnewline
\toprule
\begin{minipage}[b]{0.21\columnwidth}\raggedright
Thing
\end{minipage} & \begin{minipage}[b]{0.27\columnwidth}\raggedright
List
\end{minipage}\tabularnewline
\midrule
\endfirsthead
\toprule
\begin{minipage}[b]{0.21\columnwidth}\raggedright
Thing
\end{minipage} & \begin{minipage}[b]{0.27\columnwidth}\raggedright
List
\end{minipage}\tabularnewline
\midrule
\endhead
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.21\columnwidth}\raggedright
Thing 1
\end{minipage} & \begin{minipage}[t]{0.27\columnwidth}\raggedright
\begin{itemize}
\tightlist
\item
  Item 1
\item
  Item 2
\end{itemize}
\end{minipage}\tabularnewline
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.21\columnwidth}\raggedright
Thing 2
\end{minipage} & \begin{minipage}[t]{0.27\columnwidth}\raggedright
\begin{itemize}
\tightlist
\item
  Item 3
\item
  Item 4
\end{itemize}
\end{minipage}\tabularnewline
\bottomrule
\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

…generates this PDF:

[image: Margins in and out of the table]

If I add this to the preamble…

```
\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist[itemize]{leftmargin=*}
```

…the left margin in the list inside the table disappears, but it also disappears in the list outside the table:

[image: No margins anywhere]

If I create a custom itemize environment, I can use it in the table:

```
\newlist{marginlessitemize}{itemize}{1}
\setlist[marginlessitemize]{label=\textbullet,leftmargin=*}

...

% Inside a table cell...
\begin{marginlessitemize}
\item
  Item 1
\item
  Item 2
\end{marginlessitemize}
```

[image: No margin in, yes margin out]

That works, but because the TeX is generated automatically, I can't use the custom environment without manually editing the converted file. Hence the need to somehow automatically set no margin on lists inside tables.

Comment: Shall it work only in `longtable` or also in `tabular`, `tabularx`, etc.?

Comment: In this case, just `longtable`, but a generalized case would be interesting too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following works (just for `longtable`) if you place it in your preamble:

```
\makeatletter
\let\LT@arraybak\LT@array
\def\LT@array{\setlist[itemize]{leftmargin=*,after=\strut}\LT@arraybak}
\makeatother
```

Complete MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt,article,oneside]{memoir}

\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\makeatletter
\let\LT@arraybak\LT@array
\def\LT@array{\setlist[itemize]{leftmargin=*,after=\strut}\LT@arraybak}
\makeatother



\begin{document}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.

\begin{itemize}
\tightlist
\item
  Item 1
\item
  Item 2
\end{itemize}

\begin{longtable}[]{@{}ll@{}}
\caption{This is a table.}\tabularnewline
\toprule
\begin{minipage}[b]{0.21\columnwidth}\raggedright
Thing
\end{minipage} & \begin{minipage}[b]{0.27\columnwidth}\raggedright
List
\end{minipage}\tabularnewline
\midrule
\endfirsthead
\toprule
\begin{minipage}[b]{0.21\columnwidth}\raggedright
Thing
\end{minipage} & \begin{minipage}[b]{0.27\columnwidth}\raggedright
List
\end{minipage}\tabularnewline
\midrule
\endhead
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.21\columnwidth}\raggedright
Thing 1
\end{minipage} & \begin{minipage}[t]{0.27\columnwidth}\raggedright
\begin{itemize}
\tightlist
\item
  Item 1
\item
  Item 2
\end{itemize}
\end{minipage}\tabularnewline
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.21\columnwidth}\raggedright
Thing 2
\end{minipage} & \begin{minipage}[t]{0.27\columnwidth}\raggedright
\begin{itemize}
\tightlist
\item
  Item 3
\item
  Item 4
\end{itemize}
\end{minipage}\tabularnewline
\bottomrule
\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

[image: improved spacing]

For a short explanation: The start of the `longtable`-environment is defined as:

```
macro:->\par \ifx \multicols \@undefined \else \ifnum \col@number
>\@ne \@twocolumntrue \fi \fi \if@twocolumn \LT@err {longtable not
in 1-column mode}\@ehc \fi \begingroup \@ifnextchar [\LT@array {\LT@array
[x]}
```

So after evaluating some stuff it calls the `\LT@array` macro in which we inject our code which alters the `itemize`-environment and because it is inside of a `\begingroup...\endgroup` construct the changes made are local.

EDIT: To improve the vertical spacing I added `after=\strut` to the `\setlist`.

Comment: Oh cool! What's the logic behind this? Is `LT@array` a specific element of a longtable?

Comment: @Andrew see my edit for a short explanation.

Comment: regardless, that you solve OP problem, I would newer use such ugly table. rather use different itemize environments and concise code (which I just now delete) :)

Comment: @Zarko it might be ugly, but first: you can still alter the `\setlist`-call to include some spacing enhancements. And second: it works without any retouch of the file (except for the insertion of the redefinition).

Comment: @Zarko, @Andrew: I've made a small edit which improves the vertical spacing of the `itemize` inside of `longtable`.

Comment: @Skillmon, now is far better, I will try incorporate your solution in my deleted solution. Is it possible to generalized your solution to be aware of any type of table, not only for `longtable`?

Comment: @Zarko that's kinda hard to do. You could hack into `\@tabarray` which would at least work for `tabular` but it wouldn't work for `longtable` since `longtable` doesn't call it. I didn't look whether it would work for `tabularx` or `tabu`.

Comment: @Zarko another solution could be to alter the `itemize`-environment to check in which environment it is called and compare that to a list of known table-environments. But that's not a clean solution either, I guess -- and would fail if you have to nest it inside of a `minipage` like in `tabular`.

Comment: @Skillmon, i succeed to incorporate your solution in my answer. I afraid, that generalization is not simple or even possible. For my needs, I would be happy, if it would be possible to identify column tape `p`, `X` and `X` derivation for left aligned cells' contents. (+1) for your answer.

Answer (score 4):

Here is (hopefully) a solution with `enumitem` and `etoolbox`. If you don't want the small vertical space between 2nd and 3rd row, replace `after=\vspace*{\dimexpr1ex-\baselineskip}` with `after=vspace*{-\baselineskip}`:

```
\documentclass[11pt, article, oneside]{memoir}%
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\AtBeginEnvironment{longtable} {\setlist[itemize]{nosep, wide=0pt, leftmargin=*, before=\vspace*{-\baselineskip}, after=\vspace*{\dimexpr1ex-\baselineskip}}}

\begin{document}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.

\begin{itemize}
\tightlist
\item
  Item 1
\item
  Item 2
\end{itemize}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{longtable}{@{}>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{0.21\linewidth}>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{0.27\linewidth}@{}}%
\caption{This is a table.}\tabularnewline
\toprule
Thing & List
\tabularnewline
\midrule
\endfirsthead
\toprule
Thing & List
\tabularnewline
\midrule
\endhead
Thing 1
 &\begin{itemize}
\item
 Item 1
\item
 Item 2
\end{itemize}
\tabularnewline
Thing 2
 & \begin{itemize}
\item
 Item 3
\item
 Item 4
\end{itemize}
\tabularnewline
\bottomrule
\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: very nice and clean, @Bernard!

Comment: Ooh, I like this a lot. Redefining the `longtable` environment with `\AtBeginEnvironment` is nice and simple.

Comment: Thanks@Zarko! I had tested `>{\compress}p{...}` found on this site (it fools LaTeX, making it believe one is at the beginning of a minipage, so the `before=`vspace*{-1\baselineskip}` is not necessary), but it doesn't seem to work with `longtable`.

Comment: @Andrew: Note the ` after=` setting supposes there's nothing else in the cell after `\end{itemize}`.

Comment: Ah, good to know. Pandoc supports other paragraphs, etc. inside table cells after itemized lists. I can just rely on `\renewcommand\arraystretch{X}` to get spacing between rows (since pandoc does allow inline LaTeX)

Comment: In this case, just define a new list environment based on itemize, which you can call, say,`tabitemize` with the parameters I set, use it  if there's nothing afterwards,  and in case there's something else after the list, set the same parameters for `itemize`, except `after=...`.

Comment: @Bernard but the creation of `tabitemize` is something which he doesn't want. Still nice solution (I should definitely look into `etoolbox`).

Comment: Well, pandoc supports *minimal* inline latex, that is. I can modify arraystretch before the table, like this: https://gist.github.com/andrewheiss/10d88605e98275c2073a54bcf7be9ca2 - but I can't modify anything in the table