# Longtable and itemize - remove vertical space

Tags: spacing, longtable, itemize

My table currently looks as follows:

[image]

This is the code:

```
\begin{longtable}{|P{7cm}|P{7cm}|}
    \caption{Test table} \\
    \hline

    \rowcolor{black} \textcolor{white}{\textbf{Column 1}} & \textcolor{white}{\textbf{Column 2}}  \\ \hline

    First Row & \vspace{-\baselineskip}
    \begin{itemize}[label={--},noitemsep,leftmargin=*,topsep=0pt,partopsep=0pt]
        \item Vans (last 2 months)
        \item Cars
        \item Trucks
        \item Planes
    \end{itemize} \\ \hline

    Second Row & \vspace{-\baselineskip}
    \begin{itemize}[label={--},noitemsep,leftmargin=*,topsep=0pt,partopsep=0pt]
        \item Apple (last 2 months)
        \item Banana
    \end{itemize} \\ \hline 

\end{longtable}
```

How can I remove the vertical space in Column 2 before and after the list?

Thanks.

Comment: Take a look [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/378165/117050)

Comment: What is the `P` column type?

Answer (score 1):

Not knowing what is the `P` column type, I replaced it with `p`. Note your table a slightly too wide for the default layout of `geometry`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 10pt]{article}
\usepackage[ showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}

\begin{document}

\begingroup
\setlist[itemize]{label={--},nosep, leftmargin=*, before=\vspace*{-\baselineskip}, after=\vspace*{-0.9\baselineskip}}
\setlength{\extrarowheight}{3pt}
\begin{longtable}{|p{7cm}| p{7cm}|}
\caption{Test table} \\
\hline
\rowcolor{black} \textcolor{white}{\textbf{Column 1}} & \textcolor{white}{\textbf{Column 2}} \\ \hline
\endfirsthead
\hline
\rowcolor{black} \textcolor{white}{\textbf{Column 1}} & \textcolor{white}{\textbf{Column 2}} \\ \hline
\endhead
First Row &
\begin{itemize}
\item Vans (last 2 months)
\item Cars
\item Trucks
\item Planes
\end{itemize}
\\
\hline
Second Row & %\vspace{-\baselineskip}
\begin{itemize}%[label={--},noitemsep,leftmargin=*,topsep=0pt,partopsep=0pt]
\item Apple (last 2 months)
\item Banana
\end{itemize} \\
\hline
\end{longtable}
\endgroup

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: i think that definition of `\newcommand*{\compress}{\@minipagetrue}` is superfluous. i don't see that it is used in table :-). also you can show how to define columns widths that table is not wider than text width.

Comment: @Zark: You're right. It was a first test (ifor a shorter code), but it didn't work in this case, and I forgot to remove it. Thanks for pointing it!

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution that produces tight spacing in the second column by placing each cell in a `minipage`.

Note that I also recommend (a) not using any vertical bars and (b) using fewer, but well-spaced, horizontal bars.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry} % set page dimension parameters suitably
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\newlist{myitemize}{itemize}{1}
\setlist[myitemize]{label={--},nosep,leftmargin=*}
\usepackage{array,ragged2e,booktabs}
\setlength\extrarowheight{2pt}

\begin{document}

\begin{longtable}{p{7cm}p{7cm}}
%% set up headers and footers
\caption{Test table} \label{tab:test} \\
\rowcolor{black} 
\textcolor{white}{\textbf{Column 1}} & 
\textcolor{white}{\textbf{Column 2}}  
\\ \addlinespace
\endfirsthead

\multicolumn{2}{l}{(Table \ref{tab:test}, cont'd)}\\
\addlinespace
\rowcolor{black} 
\textcolor{white}{\textbf{Column 1}} & 
\textcolor{white}{\textbf{Column 2}}  
\\ \addlinespace
\endhead

\midrule
\multicolumn{2}{r}{(continued on next page)}\\
\endfoot

\bottomrule
\endlastfoot

%% body of table
First Row & 
\begin{minipage}[t]{7cm} % same width as overall col. width
\RaggedRight % just an educated guess...
\begin{myitemize}
    \item Vans (last 2 months)
    \item Cars
    \item Trucks
    \item Planes
\end{myitemize} 
\end{minipage}\\ 
\addlinespace
Second Row & 
\begin{minipage}[t]{7cm}
\RaggedRight
\begin{myitemize}
    \item Apple (last 2 months)
    \item Banana \strut % "\strut": a typographic strut
\end{myitemize} 
\end{minipage}\\

\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I'd put a `\strut` after the Banana, for better spacing.

Comment: @Skillmon - Great suggestion! Implemented.